# How to stop wrapping function if its already wrapped jquery on window load resize function

Tags: jquery

I have to stop a jQuery append function if its already appended on load and resize of window

```
$(document).on('load resize', function){
  $(li.mayactive).wrapAll('<span></span>');
});
```

I have also tried to use this code

```
$(document).one('load resize', function){
  $(li.mayactive).wrapAll('<span></span>');
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="myactive"><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

But its wrap once when window is loaded and again when resize of window.

Answer (score 0):

Check if parent is span (possibly with some unique attribute).

```
$(document).on('load resize', function){
    if (!$(li.mayactive).parent().is('.parent')) {
        $(li.mayactive).wrapAll('<span class="parent"></span>');
    }
});
```

---

If you have structure

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

than `.wrapAll` will make your HTML invalid:

```
<ul>
    <span class="parent">
        <li class="active"></li>
    </span>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: in this ul only one li has class myactive